# Adding Custom Font in CSS/HTML?

Tags: html, css

trying to add a custom font into my wordpress website but it's just not working. I tried using one of the plugins but I only see the change in font in 'edit mode' but when i actually go on the public webaddress the font does not load.

I've converted futura condensed light into the various types and added this in my style.css on the theme I'm using

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Conv_futura-condensedlight-normal';
    src: url('fonts/futura-condensedlight-normal.eot');
    src: url('fonts/futura-condensedlight-normal.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('fonts/futura-condensedlight-normal.woff') format('woff'),
         url('fonts/futura-condensedlight-normal.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('fonts/futura-condensedlight.svg#Conv_futura-condensedlight-normal') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

and also added this

```
h7{font-family: 'Conv_futura-condensedlight-normal';}
```

On the page where I want the text to change I have:

```
<h7>LOGIN</h7>
```

but the text does not change..

I've also uploaded the files into the fonts folder in the theme directory (where other fonts are)

Can't seem to find the bug. Help would be appreciated!

Comment: Does the developer console `<F12>` show any 404's for missing files?...

Comment: Can you post your folder structure? If for example your css is in a stylesheets or css directory your path will need adjusting?

Comment: There is no `<h7>` tag in HTML, valid range is 1 to 6.

Comment: I thought I can just increment to make a custom header? assuming everything else stays the same.. and i use style fontfamily and i still see no changes

Comment: Although it's `<h7>` and it should be corrected,  but your custom font issue isn't quite related to that IMO, reply other comments, they're all helpful.

Comment: Also double check the `mime-type` headers that the fonts are being served with. They need to be font mime-types, not something generic like `application/octet-stream`.

Comment: Font from origin '' has been blocked from loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin '' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 404.

Comment: What kind of server you're using? Google "web font cross domain".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try @font-face for custom fonts. Use below code.

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'MyWebFont';
src: url('webfont.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
src: url('webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
     url('webfont.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Super Modern Browsers */
     url('webfont.woff') format('woff'), /* Pretty Modern Browsers */
     url('webfont.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
     url('webfont.svg#svgFontName') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
}
```

and specify it as below :

```
font-family: 'MyWebFont', Fallback, sans-serif;
```

Refer : https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/using-font-face/

Comment: This is basically what I already have; the font loads properly now on IE but fails to do so on Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

They may be several reasons but the first thing I'm seeing wrong is the `<h7>` tag because it doesn't exist. You should use from [h1 to h6](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_hn.asp).

If that doesn't solve the issue please try with browser's console as @War10ck said, missing files is a signal of path issues.

Answer (score 1):

When I created a custom font and used it on my website, this was the CSS I used:

```
@font-face {font-family:'CUSTOM_FONT_NAME';src:local('CUSTOM_FONT_NAME'), url(http://MY_URL/MY_FONT_PATH/MY_FONT.ttf) format('truetype');}

.my_custom_font_class {font-family:'CUSTOM_FONT_NAME',serif;}
```

I believe I had to use a global path to get my font to load, so you might try that.
The `src:local('CUSTOM_FONT_NAME')` part is just to verify that it's working at all from your machine with the font installed. (You'll need the font name to match the name it's registered under in your machine, in this case).